# JSON Array Problems

Tags: php, json, brackets, json-rpc

I'm working with a php library called JSON-RPC Client that send to Json RPC client a JSON array like

```
{ "jsonrpc" : "2.0", "method" : "name of method", "params" : "params" , "id" : "number" }
```

I'm trying to send parameters as array to RPC Client but library send it this:

```
{ "jsonrpc" : "2.0", "method" : "nameofmethod", "params" : [{"lol": "yes"}], "id" : "number" }
```

But I would:

```
 { "jsonrpc" : "2.0", "method" : "nameofmethod", "params" : {"lol": "yes"}, "id" : "number"}
```

(These are examples, my problem are the brackets "[" and " ]" because Client doesn't accept them"). If you want, I can upload the library

This is my first question, please understand me if I write something wrong.

Comment: just provide us the code how are you sending the data.

Comment: `private function _exec($method,$params = null) {
      $result = $this->client->$method($params);
       return $result;
    }`

Comment: I think the problem might be with your Params array just try and print the result on the server side that is your Params an array or an object